# Elastic search sort field containing special characters numbers and alpahbets

Tags: java, sorting, elasticsearch

I created a case insensitive analyzer as

```
PUT /dhruv3
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "analyzer_keyword": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "about": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
        },
        "firsName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and used it in mapping. About field is supposed to contain aplha numerc and special characters.Then I inserted some values with `about` field as

> 1234, `pal, pal, ~pal

.
Besides searching I need to get result sorted. Searching is working well
but when I try to sort them as

```
GET dhruv/test/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "about": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I get results in about field as

> 1234,`pal,pal,~pal

. But I expect them to be as first special characters, then numbers and then alphabets.

I did some home work and came to know that its because of their ASCII values. SO i searched internet and tried even `asciifolding`. But didn't work out. I know there is some solution some where but I can't figure out. Please guide me

Comment: Checkout what that analyzer does to your text using the [_analyze endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).  I think the last three will just get treated as "pal".  What you need is basically no analysis except a character filter like the [Mapping Char Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) so that you can map the special characters to something that will guarantee that such string will come up first.

Answer (score 4):

You're right in that the sorting behavior you are seeing is due to the ASCII value of the special characters to be bigger than the ASCII value of digits. To be precise, looking at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), we have the following values:

- `1` has the ASCII value 49
- `   has the ASCII value 96
- `p` has the ASCII value 112
- `~` has the ASCII value 126

The [`asciifolding` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html) simply transforms characters and digits which are **NOT** in the ASCII table (i.e. first 127 characters) into their ASCII equivalent, if such one exists (e.g. `é`, `è`, `ë`, `ê` are transformed to `e`). Since all the characters above are in the ASCII table, this is not what you're looking for.

If you want the special characters to come up first in the search there are several ways.

One way to achieve it is simply to negate their ASCII value so that they will always come before the ASCII 0 character and then use script sorting:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "return doc['about'].value.chars[0].isLetterOrDigit() ? 1 : -1",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `asciifolding` has nothing to do with what you're trying to achieve. The [ASCIIFoldingFilter.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/lucene_3_0/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ASCIIFoldingFilter.java) has a wealth of information, it merely decodes unicode chars like `\uFF5E` to its ASCII equivalent in case if one can be provided as the alternative.

Adding to @Val's answer, in case you want the values sorted in the order of special chars then numbers then alphabets, you may want to consider using -

```
GET /ascii/test/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "r = doc['about'].value.chars[0]; return !r.isLetter() ? r.isDigit() ? 1 : -1 : 2",
      "type": "number",
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

Also, note this sorting may not be perfect since we only took care of first char in the script. You may want to write a robust script that takes care of entire value.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/darklow/7132077) is a good example of what you can achieve using embedded scripts.